# Swing resizing elements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm just trying out swing for java developement and can't for the life of me work out how to make a button have a specific size, or at least size how I want it to...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    int count = 0;
    JLabel label;
    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");

        JButton button = new JButton("CLick this");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256, 256));

        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks " + count);
    }
}
```

This is my basic code - I want to make the button a specific size, or size to the width of the panel, how do I do this?

Comment: Don't try to manually set the preferred size. Each Swing component has its own preferred size. `Get rid of those statements`, The layout manager may then override the preferred size based on the rules of the layout manager. So the key is to use the appropriate layout manager. With a GridLayout, each component will be the same size based on the size of the largest component.  *or size to the width of the panel,* - it is doing this. You added a Border so it won't go quite to the edge. If you want the button to have extra space you can use the `setMargins(...)` method of the button.

Comment: @camickr Thank you... just a couple of additional questions:
1) Is it good to still set the panel preferred size?
2) Should I be changing the GridLayout to something other than 0 rows and 1 col then?

Comment: I think camickr is suggesting not to do 1) and that you should use a [different layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for 2).

Comment: No. Don't set the preferred size. The layout manager will determine the preferred size based on the size of the components added to the panel. If you don't want a GridLayout, then use a different layout manager. Your requirements are not detailed enough to give a specific answer.